# How to make your YouTube video uploaded to be available only in certain countries

Tags: youtube

I really want to block some countries, and I've read about this feature, but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a feature open for users. The videos that are limited to certain countries on YouTube have been limited in that way by YouTube themselves due to licensing issues. If you want to control who should be able to view your videos, you can do this to some extent by the privacy settings, either per video or per account.

Why would you want to limit videos based on country to begin with? From a monetization standpoint it makes no sense. If you have privacy concerns, you should use the privacy options available, and make sure the video is not listed in searches for example (only visible by using the link).